# Using lock statement to read and save a list?

Tags: c#, list, thread-safety, locking, unity-game-engine

I have got a List in c# (in Unity) and I read some data from this list, if the object with the data I want is not in the list, I create the object and save it.

If two characters want the same object, the first one does not find it in the list, so it saves it in the list, but right before it does that, the second character looked in the list, did not find the object, and saves the object again: the same object would have been saved twice. How could we prevent this?

Comment: I'm confused, the title of your question seems to indicate you already know the solution: use a `lock`. So, what's the actual question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lock (list)
{
    if (!FindObject(list))
    {
        MyClass obj = CreateObject();
        list.Add(obj)
    }
}
```

This code ensures that searching the list and adding new element to it are one atomic operation. Other threads must wait for this operation to complete before starting the search.

Answer (score 1):

Using *lock* statement is one of possible solutions. Here is an example how to do so:

```
private readonly object _lock = new object();

lock (_lock)
{
    if(!list.Contains(obj))
        list.Add(obj);
}
```

Please notice that I used a private object with *lock* keyword.

You can also consider using *System.Collections.Concurrent* namespace. It might not be obvious but your scenario is supported by *ConcurrentDictionary*. The method *TryAdd* would add an element only if it doesn't already exist in a dictionary. Of course a dictionary is not the same thing as a list but maybe in would be suitable for you.

Comment: Thank you very much Michal for the explanations